# TADOTable, Seek and clUseServer how to combine?

Tags: delphi, seek, tadotable

Is it possible to use the seek function when the cursor location is set to clUseServer in Delphi's ADOTable? I know that it is possible to use locate function instead but it is a lot slower than the seek function.

Comment: Oops, I am using Access database but I am having more than 50k records in the table that I am working on and I want to avoid Locate function.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Locate, Seek (or similar function) you are retrieving all records on local. If you want to use Server Cursor (clUseServer) you must use SQL to search registers.
If you are using "Incremental Search" or trying use it, this is not a good idea in big tables with 50k records.

Regards